# angularjs error in console log for jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsfiddle, ag-grid

I am working on an Angular grid project and i am facing a minor error while using angular-grid.

Heres the error- Module 'angularGrid' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

So i thought i am missing out on something. I checked a JSfiddle and was not able to view the output there. So i checked the console for errors. here also the same error is displayed.

JSfiddle is not even edited by me. I am just viewing the link. Yet i get the same error.

http://jsfiddle.net/9b5gnjf1/8/

```
<md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-z2">
<div class="md-toolbar-tools">Toolbar</div>
```

Just adding the above 2 lines from the link so that stackoverflow lets me paste the jsfiddle link. without any code written, it doesnot allow to post the link here.

anyone knows what kind of error is this and how to solve it ?

Comment: let's clear the obvious, have you imported angularJS into your jsFiddle?

Comment: Have you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738867/module-angulargrid-is-not-available-with-ag-grid-and-hottowel

Comment: I added AngularJS 1.2.1 as a framework at the left bar of the fiddle and the error dissapeared. Now there's only some problem regarding ngMaterial instantiation.

Comment: Your angular-grid file is not loaded in JSFiddle. It shows 404 error for the file. Maybe broken link for angular-grid JS. And that is the reason angular is complaining.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the input. I got my mistake in the jsfiddle part. However, when i use angular grid in my project, it gives me tat error still. i have included scripts and modules properly. yet the error remains

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I will have a look at that link. maybe that would help me find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a 404 error resolving the external link to the javascript file that the angular-grid module lives in.

Looks like either it's a bad link, or the rawgit servers are down.

You can either wait and hope the link comes back to life, or replace the broken external resource with a working one.